# Why does the HDF5 Output Caffe layer write data of seemingly incorrect dimensions?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am interested in writing the output of a given Caffe layer to a file. I would like to do this for more than one image, so I have made some modifications to the HDF5 Output layer code to enable the creation of a file for each image which contains the features for each image. Here is the modified SaveBlobs function:

```
template <typename Dtype> void HDF5OutputLayer<Dtype>::SaveBlobs() {                               
  LOG(INFO) << "Saving HDF5 file " << file_name_ << "ds: " << ds_iter_;  
  CHECK_EQ(data_blob_.num(), label_blob_.num()) <<                       
      "data blob and label blob must have the same batch size";          

  // Open hdf5 file to write this blob                                   
  file_name_ = this->layer_param_.hdf5_output_param().file_name();          
  ostringstream appender;                                                
  appender << "_" << ds_iter_ << ".h5";                                  
  file_name_.append(appender.str());                                     
  file_id_ = H5Fcreate(file_name_.c_str(), H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT,   
                       H5P_DEFAULT);                                     
  CHECK_GE(file_id_, 0) << "Failed to open HDF5 file" << file_name_;        

  // Write the data and label                                            
  hdf5_save_nd_dataset(file_id_, HDF5_DATA_DATASET_NAME, data_blob_);       
  hdf5_save_nd_dataset(file_id_, HDF5_DATA_LABEL_NAME, label_blob_);        
  LOG(INFO) << "Successfully saved " << data_blob_.num() << " rows";        
  LOG(INFO) << "SAVEBLOB - Data size is: " << data_blob_.shape_string(); 
  LOG(INFO) << "SAVEBLOB - Label size is: " << label_blob_.shape_string();

  // Close the file                                                      
  herr_t status = H5Fclose(file_id_);                                    
  CHECK_GE(status, 0) << "Failed to close HDF5 file " << file_name_;        

  // Update iterator for next image                                      
  ds_iter_++;                                                            
}
```

The code almost works great since I am able to successfully create files for each image which do in fact contain data. Unfortunately it seems like the wrong data is being written, as both the dimensions shown in the log and in the resulting output file are incorrect. Here is where I specify my output layer (in the network prototext):

```
layer {                                                                  
  name: "conv5_3"                                                        
  type: "Convolution"                                                    
  bottom: "conv5_2"                                                      
  top: "conv5_3"                                                         
  param {                                                                
    lr_mult: 1                                                           
    decay_mult: 1                                                        
  }                                                                      
  param {                                                                
    lr_mult: 2                                                           
    decay_mult: 0                                                        
  }                                                                      
  convolution_param {                                                    
    num_output: 512                                                      
    pad: 1                                                               
    kernel_size: 3                                                       
  }                                                                      
}                                                                        
layer {                                                                  
  name: "relu5_3"                                                        
  type: "ReLU"                                                           
  bottom: "conv5_3"                                                      
  top: "conv5_3"                                                         
}                                                                        

#===== Data Logging =======                                              

layer {                                                                  
   type: "HDF5Output"                                                    
   name: "hdf5output"                                                    
   bottom: "conv5_3"   #                                                 
   bottom: "conv5_3"   #                                                 
   hdf5_output_param {                                                   
     # File name is only a base                                          
     file_name: "./test_features/image"                                  
   }                                                                     
 }
```

My reason for believing that the incorrect data is being saved is because when I observe the network setup, the dimensions for the Top of conv5_3 are shown as follows:

```
I0206 23:07:44.815330  7630 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split
I0206 23:07:44.815343  7630 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split
I0206 23:07:44.815348  7630 net.cpp:454] conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split <- conv5_3
I0206 23:07:44.815356  7630 net.cpp:411] conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split -> conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split_0
I0206 23:07:44.815366  7630 net.cpp:411] conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split -> conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split_1
I0206 23:07:44.815372  7630 net.cpp:411] conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split -> conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split_2
I0206 23:07:44.815382  7630 net.cpp:411] conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split -> conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split_3
I0206 23:07:44.815459  7630 net.cpp:150] Setting up conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split
I0206 23:07:44.815467  7630 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 512 14 14 (100352)
I0206 23:07:44.815474  7630 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 512 14 14 (100352)
I0206 23:07:44.815479  7630 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 512 14 14 (100352)
I0206 23:07:44.815484  7630 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 512 14 14 (100352)
I0206 23:07:44.815495  7630 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 116006912
I0206 23:07:44.815500  7630 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer hdf5output
I0206 23:07:44.815511  7630 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer hdf5output
I0206 23:07:44.815515  7630 net.cpp:454] hdf5output <- conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split_0
I0206 23:07:44.815521  7630 net.cpp:454] hdf5output <- conv5_3_relu5_3_0_split_1
I0206 23:07:44.815527  7630 net.cpp:150] Setting up hdf5output
I0206 23:07:44.815531  7630 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 116006912
```

So great, I expect to have data of dimensions 1 512 14 14. Unfortunately when I run inference on the model I see in my log that the wrong dimensions are showing up:

```
I0206 23:07:46.108660  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:31] Saving HDF5 file ds: 0
I0206 23:07:46.115536  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:48] Successfully saved 1 rows
I0206 23:07:46.115557  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:49] SAVEBLOB - Data size is: 1 512 54 38 (1050624)
I0206 23:07:46.115566  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:50] SAVEBLOB - Label size is: 1 512 54 38 (1050624)
I0206 23:07:46.316557  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:31] Saving HDF5 file ./test_features/image_0.h5ds: 1
I0206 23:07:46.322437  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:48] Successfully saved 1 rows
I0206 23:07:46.322456  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:49] SAVEBLOB - Data size is: 1 512 56 38 (1089536)
I0206 23:07:46.322463  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:50] SAVEBLOB - Label size is: 1 512 56 38 (1089536)
I0206 23:07:46.457828  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:31] Saving HDF5 file ./test_features/image_1.h5ds: 2
I0206 23:07:46.463618  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:48] Successfully saved 1 rows
I0206 23:07:46.463636  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:49] SAVEBLOB - Data size is: 1 512 38 50 (972800)
I0206 23:07:46.463644  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:50] SAVEBLOB - Label size is: 1 512 38 50 (972800)
I0206 23:07:46.594746  7630 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:31] Saving HDF5 file ./test_features/image_2.h5ds: 3
```

This shows that not only are the dimensions of the output incorrect, but they also vary between iterations (images)! The dimensions shown in the log match the dimensions of the data written to the h5 files, so the log is accurately describing the behavior of the code. My question is why might this be the case? It would seem that I have set everything up correctly, but there must be something that I'm missing...

Comment: Are you sure that all input images that you feed into the network have the same size?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The JPEG images are of different size, however the input data layer is specified as 1 x 3 x 224 x 224. So it looks like as far as the network is concerned all the images are the same size as they are scaled to those input dimensions.

Comment: Let me guess: your first image is 864x608 pixel, the second is 896x608 pixel, and the third is 608x800 pixel? Can you show how you load the images into the network? I.e. what data layer do you have, and how do you run caffe? I think that your modified HDF5 layer is fine, and that loading the data is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @hbaderts has helped me uncover, it turns out that the HDF5 layer is correct and does output data of the right dimensions. My confusion with dimensions was due to the seemingly static definition of input dimensions in the testing version of the network prototext. It turns out that because I am loading in data by using the pycaffe function net.forward(**forward_kwargs) the convolutional layers are scaling themselves to meet the varied input dimensions of my input images. This explains both the larger than expected feature dimensions and the fact that they vary between images.